# how to associate android xml resources to default editor in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to open all the xml(all under res folder) files in android project with default xml editor instead of Andriod related one.

I have tried below setting

`Preferences => General => Editors => File Association => *.xml => set 'XML editor' as default`

Even after with the above setting, all files under layout files are opening with Android layout editor.

Is there any other settings we need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Right click > Open with...
The choice should be memorized for all XML files.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me too. But I think you if you don't want the layout view you can click on the xml tab (the one that appears in the bottom of the editor and has the file name as the title) and it displays the xml content as such.